# Leaking when tried to free vector element

Tags: visual-c++, memory-leaks

please help to figure this out.
I have some leaking code, and I don't know how to handle it

```
vector <ItemClass> items( 10 );
items[1] = ItemClass( "DVD Player", 560 );
items[5] = * new ItemClass( "Blu Ray Player", 900 );
```

How should I free memory for items[5] ?
I'm getting error on my attempts of freeing memory

```
delete &items[5];

delete [] &items[5];
```

I even tried something like

```
ItemClass * delItem = &items[5];
items[5] = item4;
delete delItem;
```

I'm getting "corruption of the heap" in VS2010 Ultimate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a strange use and mix up of storing new-allocated objects in vectors in your code. Usually you should handle lists all in the same way. Thus my examples below will be more explicit, and independent from each other which should help you understand the differences.

Use `delete` for objects only. See code below.

Use `delete []` for "native" arrays only, not for vector or similar container classes or objects inside them.

I will not give an example for arrays though, since arrays might be more confusing.

Default example stack:

```
vector <ItemClass> items( 10 );

// does not need to be deleted because item is on the stack
ItemClass item("device1", "10"); 
items.push_back(item);
```

Default example with heap allocation:

```
vector <ItemClass*> items( 10 );

ItemClass* pItem = new ItemClass("device2", "20");
items.push_back(pItem);

// delete all items inside vector
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
{
    ItemClass* pToDelete = items[i];
    delete pToDelete;
    items.erase(i);
}
```

**The following examples should be avoided and are for clarifying things up only! Use at own risk.**

Storing addresses of stack variables:

```
vector <ItemClass*> items( 10 );

// does not need to be deleted because item is on the stack
ItemClass item("device3", "30"); 
items.push_back( &item ); // storing a reference to item

// No need to delete this item that points to something on the stack.
// However you might not be able to tell items apart which have been 
// created on the heap or the stack, so just dont do it.
```

If you mix up with the example before and store references and pointers you must handle it yourself. My recommendation: Do not do this.

Storing dereferenced items:

```
vector <ItemClass> items( 10 );

ItemClass* pItem = new ItemClass("device4", "40"); 
items.push_back(*pItem);

// must be deleted because allocated on the heap
// Again you can not tell which item is allocated on stack or heap. Avoid this.
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't call `delete` on objects that you don't own.  You don't own `items[5]`.  The `items` vector owns it.

What you need to `delete` is the `ItemClass` object that you are currently leaking, which is the one you are creating via `new ItemClass(...)` and then copying to `items[5]`.

```
ItemClass *temp = new ItemClass("Blue Ray Player", 900);
items[5] = *temp;
delete temp;
```

If you want to remove `items[5]` from the vector, ask the vector to remove it:

```
items.erase(items.begin() + 5);
```

Note that this may be rather inefficient, because all later items in the vector have to be moved down one position, which entails calling the `ItemClass` assignment operator once for each moved item.

You might want to use a vector of pointers to `ItemClass` instead, or a vector of `shared_ptr`s, or a `boost::ptr_vector`.

Comment: Thank you Rob, I forgot about object ownership

Comment: Am I right? object created with "new ItemClass( "Blu Ray Player", 900 )" was allocated then copied (by using copy constructor) to items[5] and finaly pointer to the first object were lost?

Comment: Technically it was copied using the assignment operator, not the copy constructor.  The rest of your comment is correct.